# How to simplify these methods to avoid confusion?

Tags: c#, .net

I've come here today to ask a question about these methods. I've taken lead on a personal project as a hobby and unfortunately I can't contact the old developer to ask what these methods even do. I'm pretty new to C# so I was asking if anyone could help me in simplifying them, to avoid the confusion I'm having? If anyone could actually tell me what they do also that would really help.

I'm just a little confused about them as of now... They were in the utilities folder. The project is an emulation server for a game, sending and receiving packets is the main focus.

```
public static int DecodeInt32(byte[] v)
{
    if ((v[0] | v[1] | v[2] | v[3]) < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return (v[0] << 0x18) + (v[1] << 0x10) + (v[2] << 8) + v[3];
}

public static int DecodeInt16(byte[] v)
{
    if ((v[0] | v[1]) < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return (v[0] << 8) + v[1];
}
```

Here is a part of code that uses them, might help in finding out?

```
using (BinaryReader Reader = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(Data)))
{
    if (Data.Length < 4)
        return;

    int MsgLen = Utilities.DecodeInt32(Reader.ReadBytes(4));

    if ((Reader.BaseStream.Length - 4) < MsgLen)
    {
        this._halfData = Data;
        this._halfDataRecieved = true;
        return;
    }
    else if (MsgLen < 0 || MsgLen > 5120)//TODO: Const somewhere.
        return;

    byte[] Packet = Reader.ReadBytes(MsgLen);

    using (BinaryReader R = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(Packet)))
    {
        int Header = Utilities.DecodeInt16(R.ReadBytes(2));

        byte[] Content = new byte[Packet.Length - 2];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(Packet, 2, Content, 0, Packet.Length - 2);

        ClientPacket Message = new ClientPacket(Header, Content);

        try
        {
            Server.GetGame().GetPacketManager().TryExecutePacket(this, Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ExceptionLogger.LogException(e);
        }

        this._deciphered = false;
    }

    if (Reader.BaseStream.Length - 4 > MsgLen)
    {
        byte[] Extra = new byte[Reader.BaseStream.Length - Reader.BaseStream.Position];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(Data, (int)Reader.BaseStream.Position, Extra, 0, (int)(Reader.BaseStream.Length - Reader.BaseStream.Position));

        this._deciphered = true;
        HandleMoreData(Extra);
    }
}
```

Comment: `DecodeInt32` is basically converting byte array into 32bit integer.

Comment: It is calculating from the first 4 bytes of the data how many data is incoming, and stores it internally (the halfdata part) if not enough data was recieved yet. - probably to be used later when more of that data is recieved.The `<<` parts in the Decode is simple bitshifting of byte 's (8bit each) to calculate the 16bit or 32bit integer that denotes the size of the stream in the lower part of your code. Look up the documentation about your games Packetmanager and packets and how they are used.

Comment: As far as I know, `(v[0] | v[1] | v[2] | v[3])` can not be less than zero.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem why? Its a bit-or of bytes producing a byte. byte can go to -128

Comment: @PatrickArtner: no, an `sbyte` ranges from -128 to 127, a `byte` from 0 to 255. In case you assign `-1` to a byte, you get `(1,12): error CS0031: Constant value `-1' cannot be converted to a `byte'`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem shameonme - youre right

Comment: Do you know [BitConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) from .NET?

Comment: Thank you for all the comments, although I still can't find a way to simplify it, is this one of them methods that can't be simplified as its a complex operation, or is the previous developer just over doing it?

Comment: @SirRufo I've not come across it yet no.

Comment: You might want to touch up on C# if you find this complex - sorry. It is simply parsing incoming stream data , the first few byts hold how much data is incoming and buffers data until all data is there. Its package handling, not rocket science ;) If its working, I would treat it as a black box until I groke how the package stuff if designed as to not break code that is split over your end and the one sending the data

Answer (score 2):

The `BinaryReader` has the methods `ReadInt16` and `ReadInt32` (and many others). Therefore you could replace the decoding methods.

```
int MsgLen = Utilities.DecodeInt32(Reader.ReadBytes(4));
```

becomes

```
int MsgLen = Reader.ReadInt32();
```

I assume that the [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the bytes is right for the `BinaryReader` methods.

Comment: @mihi Shame on me! Thank you, mate :)

Comment: ReadInt32 reads the bytes in the opposite order https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binaryreader.cs,95b16031011c2e9f

Comment: Thanks for this, although .ReadInt32() doesn't take into account that I'm reading 4 does it? It's also in the opposite order.

Comment: `ReadInt16` reads two bytes. `ReadInt32` reads four bytes. Both advance the cursor by this number of bytes. Depending on the  endianness of the bytes in the source stream, they might do the right thing or not. If you want to be sure, make a test.